# TypeScript React / MobX "Too many re-renders" on component disabled callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

I have a submit button a form that has a dependency on the following computed MobX function

```js
  @computed
  isSurveySubmitEnabled = (): boolean => {
    let questionsToValidate = [];

    switch (this.surveyType) {
      case "preSurvey": {
        questionsToValidate = PRE_SURVEY_QUESTIONS;
      }
      case "postSurvey": {
        questionsToValidate = POST_SURVEY_QUESTIONS;
      }
      case "postTest": {
        questionsToValidate = POST_TEST_QUESTIONS;
      }
    }

    runInAction(() => {
      this.isValidated = true;
    });

    questionsToValidate.forEach((qObj: any) => {
      qObj.value.forEach((qVal: any) => {
        if (qVal.type === "date") {
          if (!this.entryPostParams[qVal.entryIdYear]) {
            runInAction(() => {
              this.isValidated = false;
            });
          }
        } else {
          if (!this.entryPostParams[qVal.entryId]) {
            runInAction(() => {
              this.isValidated = false;
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });

    return this.isValidated;
  };
```

The callback is used in the `disabled` attribute on the button as follows

```
 <Button disabled={!isSurveySubmitEnabled()} style={{ marginTop: '5%' }} onClick={() => { doSubmitForm(); incrementActivityIndex() }}>Submit</Button>
```

I would expect this to run only when there is a change to the `this.entryPostParams` observable that's being used in my callback, but I get the following errors when the component renders

```
The above error occurred in the <GoogleForm> component:
    in GoogleForm (at PageContent.tsx:32)
    in PageContent (at Continue.tsx:52)
    in Continue (at App.tsx:12)
    in Route (at App.tsx:12)
    in App (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter(App) (at src/index.tsx:12)
    in Router (at src/index.tsx:11)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit [url] to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
```

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14815)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17034)
    at updateSimpleMemoComponent (react-dom.development.js:16972)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18687)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21756)
    at react-dom.development.js:11089
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11072)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:22883)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:22820)
    at react-dom.development.js:22699
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:597)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:552)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:164)
```

Following the stack trace it's not clear what the problem is.  Shouldn't this callback only be executed when there are changes to an observable?

Answer (score 1):

It is discouraged to run actions inside computed getters and probably the cause for too many rerenders. Each runInAction has the potential to cause a retrigger of an observer, and obviously, when an underlying observable of a computed getter is changed, the computed value itself has likely changed. Meaning, the observer that uses said computed value also has to be notified that there was a change and retriggers. You may see the potential for endless loops here.

You should also collect the changed observables and try to push all changes in one batch through an action to minimize rerenders. The outermost action in mobx decides if an transaction has ended or not and if observers gets updated. This means actions inside actions dont notify observers individually, but a computed getter is no action. Each runInAction that is run individually in your case causes a reaction.

TL;DR: Dont run actions inside computed getters and dont loop over runInAction.

Comment: Does this mean an observable should not be changed in a computed getter at all?  One of the things I tried previously was to scope isValidated just to that function, but then the computed only ran on first render, despite this.entryPostParams being an observable.

Comment: The point of computed getters is that they cache the result. Conceptually they are observables themself. You just could calculate isValidated without saving it and be done with it. It only gets recalculated when entryPostParams or surveyType is changed. I don't know if that's sufficient for your case, but something like this should be the approach for computed getters. And yes, optimally, you don't change observables in computed getters.

Comment: It seems like even after removing actions the computed only runs on component load and I'm certain that entryPostParams is being changed.  Could it have something to do how I'm observing entryPostParams in this context?

Comment: If you can give me a stackblitz url or a minimal repo I can debug it for you.